# Crossing of monotone function with linear function

Tags: inequality

Suppose $F(x)$ is a continuous monotone increasing function of an argument $x\in(0,x_M)$.

To show that $F(x)<x\quad\forall x\in(0,x_M)$, is it enough to show that 
$F(0)<0$ and $F(x_M)<x_M$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not correct; $F(x)=\sqrt{x}-\frac{1}{6}$ is strictly increasing on $[0,1]$, $F(0)=-\frac{1}{6}<0$, $F(1)=1-\frac{1}{6}<1$, but $$F\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)=\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}-\frac{1}{6}>\frac{2}{3}-\frac{1}{6}=\frac{1}{2}.$$